# How to fix 'ImportError: cannot import name base' when deploying to app engine standard environment?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-docs-api

I have created a simple, Google App Engine application that works with the Google docs api.

it requires the `app_engine` module from `google.auth` (from google.auth import app_engine), which I have installed in a `/lib` folder and added `vendor.add('lib')` to `appengine_config.py`

However, when I deploy from google cloud SDK to the app engine standard environment, I am getting the following error:

> 'importError: cannot import name base'

I am also getting the error:

> 'ImportError: No module named pyasn1.codec.der'

For both issues I have doubled checked that the base and `pyasn1.codec.der` modules are actually present in the `lib` folder. In both cases they are.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

```
from google.auth import app_engine
import googleapiclient.discovery
```

Full tacebacks here:

**base**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/7679791231c143f9/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/7679791231c143f9/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/7679791231c143f9/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~emailtest69/20190507t182648.418021119853034691/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    from google.auth import app_engine
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~emailtest69/20190507t182648.418021119853034691/lib/google/auth/app_engine.py", line 29, in <module>
    from google.auth import crypt
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~emailtest69/20190507t182648.418021119853034691/lib/google/auth/crypt/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from google.auth.crypt import base
ImportError: cannot import name base
```

**pyasn1.codec.der**

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/7679791231c143f9/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/7679791231c143f9/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/7679791231c143f9/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~emailtest69/20190507t182648.418021119853034691/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    from google.auth import app_engine
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~emailtest69/20190507t182648.418021119853034691/lib/google/auth/app_engine.py", line 29, in <module>
    from google.auth import crypt
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~emailtest69/20190507t182648.418021119853034691/lib/google/auth/crypt/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from google.auth.crypt import rsa
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~emailtest69/20190507t182648.418021119853034691/lib/google/auth/crypt/rsa.py", line 27, in <module>
    from google.auth.crypt import _python_rsa
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~emailtest69/20190507t182648.418021119853034691/lib/google/auth/crypt/_python_rsa.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pyasn1.codec.der import decoder
ImportError: No module named pyasn1.codec.der
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Python modules and objects are properly installed.
Note that in App Engine Python runtime environment, Python client libraries must be vendored into your application as they are not installed in it.

More references are discussed here[1] specific for Google Docs API.

Also make sure that you have obtained credentials with [2]:

from google.auth import app_engine
credentials = app_engine.Credentials()

Since the error is coming from google.auth.crypt module you may also check on this page[3] for more info.

[1] https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/libraries#python
[2] https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/master/docs/user-guide.rst#the-app-engine-standard-environment
[3] https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.crypt.html#module-google.auth.crypt

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I go to "google" directory and delete the "auth" manually.
After I run

```
pip install google-auth
```

and it's start working.